# ASP.NET MVC - Model binding for generated form inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have an application which user can define as many questions as he wants, these questions must be answered by other users in the application, each question's item has two properties (`Id`, `Value`) but the problem is that when I post the form, the default model binding will post all inputs on the form.

Here's the model:

```
public class Question
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<QuestionItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public FieldType FieldType { get; set; }
}

public enum FieldType
{
    RadioButton,
    CheckBox,
    Text
}

public class QuestionResponse
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ResponseValue> Values { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseValue
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var questions = new List<Question>
        {
            new Question { Title = "Question One", Items = new List<QuestionItem>
            {
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item One", FieldType = FieldType.RadioButton },
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item Two", FieldType = FieldType.RadioButton },
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item Two", FieldType = FieldType.RadioButton },
            } },
            new Question { Title = "Question Two", Items = new List<QuestionItem>
            {
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item One", FieldType = FieldType.CheckBox },
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item Two", FieldType = FieldType.CheckBox },
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item Two", FieldType = FieldType.CheckBox },
            } },
            new Question { Title = "Question Three", Items = new List<QuestionItem>
            {
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item One", FieldType = FieldType.RadioButton },
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item Two", FieldType = FieldType.RadioButton },
                new QuestionItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Item Two", FieldType = FieldType.RadioButton },
            } }
        };
        return View(questions);
    }

    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(QuestionResponse model)
    {
        var form = this.Request.Form;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using TestFormGenerator.Models
@model IList<Question>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">@Model[i].Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @for (var j = 0; j <= Model[i].Items.Count - 1; j++)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">@Model[i].Items[j].Title</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">

                                @switch (Model[i].Items[j].FieldType)
                                {
                                    case FieldType.RadioButton:

                                        @Html.RadioButton(string.Format("Values[{0}].Id", i), Model[i].Items[j].Id)

                                        break;
                                    case FieldType.CheckBox:

                                        @Html.CheckBox(string.Format("Values[{0}].Id", j), Model[i].Items[j].Id)

                                        break;
                                    case FieldType.Text:
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                                }

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">

                                @Html.TextBox(string.Format("Values[{0}].Value", i))

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="pull-left">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
}
```

[Here's the working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IWNYYI) in case you want test it.

any idea?

Comment: What are you expecting? Your creating form controls for `IList<Question>`. And the model in the POST method is `QuestionResponse model` - they are not the same.

Comment: @StephenMuecke The view must display both Question and its items.

Comment: And in order to do that you should be creating a view model representing that, not trying to make hacks to have one model in the view and a different model in the POST method. And you code for `Question Two` makes no sense - your want a checkbox (i.e. a Yes/No answer yet your generating 3 items associated with the question. Its a bit hard to understand what you really want here.